# Input data: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2 "

Tags: java, parsing, numberformatexception

Here is my data from the text file:

```
21/08/12#ESE-6329#PV/5732#30
27/08/12#PEA-4567#PV/5732#3@
11/09/12#ESE-5577#Xk/8536#2
14/09/12#PNW-1235#HY/7195#2@
```

And this is a code form the main method:

```
File orderData = new File("PurchaseOrderData.txt");            
Scanner dataScan = new Scanner(orderData);

while(dataScan.hasNextLine())
{
    String lineData = dataScan.nextLine();

    Scanner lineScan = new Scanner(lineData);
    lineScan.useDelimiter("#");

    String date = lineScan.next(); // line 259
    String id = lineScan.next();
    String code = lineScan.next();

    String quantityPlus = lineScan.next();

    if(!quantityPlus.contains("@"))
        management.addNewPurchaseOrder(date, id, code, 
                                    Integer.parseInt(quantityPlus)); // line 267
    else
    {
        quantityPlus = quantityPlus.replace("@", "");
        management.addNewPurchaseOrder(date, id, code,
                                    Integer.parseInt(quantityPlus));
        management.startNewMonth();
    }
```

On the first instance of

```
management.addNewPurchaseOrder(date, id, code, Integer.parseInt(quantityPlus));
```

I get this exception:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2 "
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at Assignment2.MainTest.main(MainTest.java:267)
```

If I do:

```
String quantityPlus = lineScan.next();
quantityPlus = quantityPlus.replace(" ", "");
```

I get the following:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1371)
    at Assignment2.MainTest.main(MainTest.java:259)
```

MainTest.java:259 - `String date = lineScan.next();`

I've tried to use `nextInt()` as well, but the result is the same. What is wrong there?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: is there a chance that you have some hidden symbol after `2` or `2@` in lines 3 or 4 respectively?

Comment: actually which line throws an exception, 3rd or 4th?

Comment: @Sergey Pauk Yes, thanks, found it and cleared! But now there is:                 NoSuchElementException mentioned above...

Comment: @Sergey Pauk  I've got quite a lot of lines of data, it was just an example, but the structure is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MainTest.java:259 - `String date = lineScan.next();`
You should check before if the line is not empty this might be why the scanner is throwing an exception

Comment: I seems that is helped! Thank you! But is that, if I read from a String, which has the data exactly for the number of times I mentioned .next()?

Comment: If you are using a while loop there the loop is called as long as there is a new line char at the end of the current line, you might also need to catch this exception in case the line is in invalid format

Answer (score 1):

Regarding `NoSuchElementException` - one of your lines ends prematurely (most likely there's no data after the last `#`). As you can see from [specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()) this exception is thrown when:

> @throws NoSuchElementException if no more tokens are available